# How to download an image from a remore URL if it's on HTTPS Url

Tags: image, image-processing, https

I need to download images from a HTTPS URL. i know we can download images using cURL from a remote HTTP url but it fails for HTTPS Protocol, it return blank image.

Any special trick to do that ? Website i have to download images from is amazon.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl` will work fine for HTTPS. From the man page:

```
   curl  is  a  tool to transfer data from or to a server, using one of the
   supported protocols (DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP,  HTTPS,  IMAP,
   IMAPS,  LDAP,  LDAPS,  POP3,  POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS,
   TELNET and TFTP).  The command is designed to work without user interac-
   tion.
```

You're likely running into certificate validation issues.
You can tell `curl` to ignore these, see the `-k` option:

```
   -k, --insecure
          (SSL)  This  option  explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure"
          SSL connections and transfers. All SSL connections are  attempted
          to be made secure by using the CA certificate bundle installed by
          default. This makes all connections  considered  "insecure"  fail
          unless -k, --insecure is used.

          See     this     online    resource    for    further    details:
          http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

Comment: This line of code resolved my issue. Thanks for the help , again.